# Explicitly Computing a Lie Transported Vector or Covector

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, vector-fields

I'm having difficulty understanding how to physically compute how a covector changes under Lie transport.

Suppose on $\mathbb{R}^2$ I have a vector field $V=x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}.$ Suppose also that I have a covector, for example $\omega=2dx$ at the point $(1,1)$. I would like to compute $\omega|_{(2,2)}$ by following an integral curve of $V$ passing through $(1,1)$.

How does one physically compute this? I know that the Lie derivative here will be
$(\mathcal{L}_V\omega)_\mu=V^\nu \partial_\nu \omega_\mu+\omega_\nu\partial_\mu V^\nu.$
My attempt has been to solve for an integral curve $\gamma$ through $(1,1)$, which I think involves solving $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=x$ $\implies \gamma=(e^t,e^t)$. I can then compute the Lie derivative by plugging in the components. I'm unsure how to proceed from there. I imagine I'm supposed to integrate this somehow. Should I be using the diffeomorphism formula to do this? This isn't a homework problem, just an example problem so don't worry about spoiling the answer.